# Issue of Duplicate cell content in last cell and last row while Copying table from one docx file to other docx file using docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

//*I am trying to copy a table from one document of docx file to other document of docx file. But last cell of my table and last row are getting duplicated along with content in the last cell. Rest all is working fine. I am able to copy complete table but only when it come to last cell and last row , i am getting duplicate. It Will be very helpful, if someone could guide me , exactly where i am doing mistakes , i have tried it for complete 2 days but it didn't work.

This is my complete code and i am trying with only one table in file nothing else.
*//

public class ExtractTables {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JAXBException, IOException, Docx4JException {
    try {
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage;

        wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File("D://Table.docx"));
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();

        ExtractTables wordExt = new ExtractTables();
        wordExt.extractTable(factory, documentPart);

    } catch (Docx4JException DOE) {
        System.out.println("The exception is : ");
        DOE.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

private void extractTable(ObjectFactory objFact, MainDocumentPart documentPart) throws Docx4JException {
        try {
            WordprocessingMLPackage wml = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

```
        int noTbls = 0;
        int noRows = 0;
        int noCells = 0;
        int noParas = 0;
        int noTexts = 0;

        List<Object> allTables = getAllElementFromObject(documentPart, Tbl.class);
        for (Object table : allTables) {
            noTbls++;
            Tbl tbl = (Tbl) table;

            Tr tr = null;
            Tc tc = null;
            P p = null;
            R r = null;
            Text txt = null;
            // Get all the Rows in the table
            List<Object> allRows = getAllElementFromObject(tbl, Tr.class);

            for (Object row : allRows) {
                tr = (Tr) row;

                noRows++;
                // Get all the Cells in the Row
                List<Object> allCells = getAllElementFromObject(tr, Tc.class);
                for (Object cell : allCells) {
                    tc = (Tc) cell;

                    noCells++;
                    // Get all the Paragraph's in the Cell
                    List<Object> allParas = getAllElementFromObject(tc, P.class);
                    for (Object par : allParas) {
                        p = (P) par;
                        noParas++;
                        // Get all the Run's in the Paragraph
                        List<Object> allRuns = getAllElementFromObject(p, R.class);

                        for (Object runs : allRuns) {
                            r = (R) runs;

                            // Get the Text in the Run
                            List<Object> allText = getAllElementFromObject(r, Text.class);
                            for (Object text : allText) {
                                noTexts++;
                                txt = (Text) text;

                            }
                            System.out.println("No of Text in Para No: " + noParas + "are: " + noTexts);
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("No of Paras in Cell No: " + noCells + "are: " + noParas);
                }
                System.out.println("No of Cells in Row No: " + noRows + "are: " + noCells);

            }
            System.out.println("No of Rows in Table No: " + noTbls + "are: " + noRows);

            r.getContent().add(txt);
            p.getContent().add(r);
            tc.getContent().add(p);
            tr.getContent().add(tc);
            tbl.getContent().add(tr);

            wml.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(tbl);
            wml.save(new File("D://TestTable.docx"));

        }
        System.out.println("Total no of Tables: " + noTbls);

    }

    catch (Docx4JException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

private static List getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class toSearch) {

```
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();

    if (obj instanceof JAXBElement)
        obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();

    if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch))

        result.add(obj);

    else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {

        List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();

        for (Object child : children) {

            result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

}

Comment: Above is the complete code which i have placed in step by step formate. I am facing issue with duplicate last cell content with 4 time repeat and duplicate last row. kindly check it will be very helpfull to me

Comment: You could just clone the Tbl object, but you wouldn't be handling any rels, managing styles etc.

Comment: @JasonPlutext it would be helpful if you could share some link , where i will be able to go through it ,i.e clone the Tbl object . Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/XmlUtils.java#L1014